# Stop nodemon programmatically after run

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm working on an API that runs in the background, we have some helper methods that need to be launch as such `nodemon --exec babel-node commands/router.js` to display all routes for instance.

Note that `node commands/router.js` cannot work as we need babel

At the moment, the method runs without problem but I need to stop nodemon from running after execution. I understand that nodemon is supposed to keep running after execution but our project is designed as such and I need to use nodemon for execution and then kill it.

How can I kill/stop nodemon after run?

**Code**

package.json

```
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
    "router": "nodemon --exec babel-node commands/router.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

router.js

```
const script = () => {
  // Fetch and display routes
}

script()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

From Nodemon documentation, the correct way to handle this use case is to manually kill the process with the `gracefulShutdown` method, like so:

```
process.once('SIGUSR2', function () {
  gracefulShutdown(function () {
    process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
  });
});
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just tried
`
import nodemon from "nodemon"; // <= Need to import like that
const script = () => {
  // Fetch and display routes
}
script()
nodemon.emit("quit");
`
But that didn't work, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that's the strategy I was thinking. I just went back to the Nodemon docs, and I've edited my answer to show their recommended strategy.

Comment: For some reason it's not working, I'll post the solution once found. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution by removing nodemon and manually ending scripts with `process.exit()`

**Final code**

package.json

```
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js", // <= still called with nodemon
    "router": "babel-node commands/router.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

router.js

```
const script = () => {
  // Fetch and display routes

  process.exit()
}

script()
```